# Convert a N-Bytes to a Float defined by the Q-Number

Tags: java, floating-point, arrays

Is there an easy way to convert a byte array of N bytes to a float defined by the Q-Number.

In 2's Compliment (Forgot To mention this before)

Example: 0xFFF0 -> Float-point using a s3.12 Q-Number

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)

Comment: Read 2 byte shorts, extract the sign, divide by 4096.0 and use `-` if negative.

Comment: What do you mean by read 2 byte short? I understand the "divide by 4096" 2^12.

Comment: A `s3.12` Q-Number is 16 bits, aka 2 bytes, so read 2 bytes from array as a short value. You can't read all bytes from N-byte array as a single `s3.12` Q-Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following suggestion by Peter Lawrey:

```
private static void test(short x) {
    float y = (float)(x & 0x7FFF) / (1 << 12);
    if ((x & 0x8000) != 0)
        y = -y;
    System.out.printf("%04x: %g%n", x, y);
}
```

*Test*

```
test((short)0xFFF0);
test((short)0xFFFF);
test((short)0x0000);
test((short)0x0001);
test((short)0x1000);
test((short)0x9000);
test((short)0x7FFF);
```

*Output*

```
fff0: -7.99609
ffff: -7.99976
0000: 0.00000
0001: 0.000244141
1000: 1.00000
9000: -1.00000
7fff: 7.99976
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
byte[] bytes = ....
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.????); // check your byte order
while(bb.remaining() > 1) {
    short s = bb.getShort();
    boolean signed = s < 0;
    int value = s & 0x7FFF;
    double d = s / 4096.0;
    if (signed)
        d = -d;
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Comment: This will take care of endianness.  Thanks Peter!!